Event for 'go back' browser action in Angular v17
I have a Symfony application. In the frontend, I'm using Angular v17 and Twig. I want to add an event on the Angular side that is triggered when the user clicks on the browser's 'Go back' button.
I tried to use ngOnDestroy, but when I clicked on this button, I didn't find any result.

Can you provide more context and your current code ?

Back button is not part of Angular, so it's not listening for it.

Does this answer your question? Angular 2 How to detect back button press using router and location.go()?
